# PHP: How do I convert a regular expression to an example match?

Tags: php, regex

I have a regular expression for matching URIs. For example,

```
preg_match("/^my\/uri\//i", "my/uri/whatever");
```

Which I use for routing, for exmample "http://www.mywebsite.com/my/uri/page.html" will match the above (with the protocol/host removed of course).

Is there any way to evaluate the regular expression into the most general URI that will match? For example,

"my/uri/"

Comment: You just want your current regexp to match either `"my/uri"` and `"my/uri/*"`?

Comment: What an interesting question. It'll be fairly tough to handle things like '/\w\b.+\b\s/' (one solution: 'a a ').

Comment: I want to kind of reverse engineer the regex into the most simplified form

Comment: Tell us what you would be using it for. In this case, "most general URI" is a subjective concept for anything but the simplest regexes (e.g. what's the most general form of the regex "`...`"?).

Comment: Ok so basicly I have a dynamicly built sitemap.xml which lists URIs in my site.              
However my site is built using dynamic routing...
So I have for example the following routes (expressed in regex)
- `/^projects\/view\//i`
- `/^sitemap.xml/i`
The above to match:
- `projects/view/`
- `sitemap.xml`

Basicly what Im asking is how can I convert a regex string into what it will match (in the most basic form).

Comment: In that case, it's really so much a regex as a prefix string with escaped slashes. If you use a different delimiter character, you can avoid the escaping too: `preg_match('~my/uri/~i', ...)`.

Comment: @Max The most basic/general form can be reasonably defined here as the shortest form. Good suggestion on using a different delimiter, though.

Comment: Here's a very limited implementation of regex expansion:

http://pagesperso-orange.fr/joseph.rezeau/eao/developpement/expandRegexpToString.htm#

Comment: Here's the opposite: http://txt2re.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand what you actually want.

This code might be what you need:

```
$general_uri = 'my/uri/';
$regex = '/^' . preg_quote($general_uri) . '/i';
```

If you want reverse of the above code:

```
$regex = '/^my\/uri\//i';
$general_uri = str_replace('\\', '', preg_replace('/^\/\^(.*)\/i?$/', '$1', $regex));
```

However above code will not work on complicated regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you can tell the original problem that leads you into this dead end someone can give a twist on the situation.

I've made myself a routing algoritm and I just use and explode on '/' and it works very nicely, something like [Magento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magento) or [Zend Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Framework) does it, registering path controllers or routers and linking them.

Maybe your original problem can be solved without need to write a regular expression engine with PHP.