# PHP: How do I strip all regex?

Tags: php, regex

How do strip all regex special characters from a string?

eg: I have "`/^bla\/bla\/bla\//i`" which I want to be: "`bla/bla/bla/`"

---

I guess this is not really possible in the context I was thinking of. Thanks for your responses

Comment: What would you like to do with look-arounds? And what about meta characters like `.` (dot), or character classes like `[abc]`? Etc. etc. Please first define what subset of regex you want to handle.

Comment: Is this a restatement of this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216494/php-how-do-i-convert-a-regular-expression-to-an-example-match  If so please close one of them

Comment: How would you want parentheticals handled? If you had `/^bla\/(bla)\/bla\//i` would you want `bla//bla/` or do you just want the parenthesis gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but are you maybe looking for the preg_quote ( http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php ) function ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do, but if you just want to remove certain characters from a string you might be better off using [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php).  For one thing it'll be *much* faster than doing a regex, and it'll probably be more readable as well.

edit: Actually I really don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The OP didn't say he was trying to *use* a regex, but rather trying to *transform* a regex representing a string into another string.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that after I posted.  Now I'm confused.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to remove this answer then?

Comment: Well, I'll admit, it's a pretty poorly formed question, i.e. it would be better to see real data, and the real desired outcome, and then we could define a more elegant solution...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php 
    $string = "/^bla\/bla\/bla\//i";
    $patterns = array(
        "/\/\^([\w]+)/i" => "$1/",
        "/[\/]{2,}i$/i" => "/",
        "/\\\/" => "",
        "/[\/]{2,}/" => "/",
        "/\/$/" => "",
    );
    echo preg_replace(array_keys($patterns),$patterns,$string);

    //OR, this:
    echo    "\n";

    $string = "/^bla\/bla\/bla\//i";
    $pattern = "/(?![\/\w]$)([\w]+)/";
    preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$matches);
    echo join('/',$matches[0]);
?>
```

Comment: Some individuals may disagree with splitting up regex into pieces of logical operations as in the first example, that's a style choice. Still, the bottom method is prefered I would think, better to capture what you do want, than to bother replacing what you don't want.